# f# async cancel or continue

Tags: asynchronous, f#

How do I implement an async function that will check each result of multiple parallel async functions and cancels them all if a certain result is found (say a bool returns false). Otherwise it will let all the async functions complete then return the final result (say bool true).  I have tried Async.Choice from the F# snippets site, but it uses Async.FromContinuations that will only let you call the continuation once.

Comment: You should try using Rx.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an `async` that does some work:

```ml
let computeSomething (x : int) =
  async {
    do! Async.Sleep (x * 1000)

    return x * 2 + x
  }
```

Let's add in some extra code so that we can see if cancellation happens:

```ml
let computeSomething (x : int) =
  async {
    // To prove that cancellation is happening
    use! watcher =
      Async.OnCancel
        (fun () -> printfn $"Computation for %i{x} was cancelled")

    do! Async.Sleep (x * 1000)

    return x * 2 + x
  }
```

Now, we can run many of these in parallel using `Async.Parallel`:

```ml
async {
  let! results =
    [
      for x in [ 1; 7; 2; 3; 4; 5 ] do
        computeSomething x
    ]
    |> Async.Parallel

  printfn "%A" results
}
```

`Async.Parallel` has a useful property where if one task fails, the remaining tasks get cancelled.

So, we can wrap `computeSomething` into an `async` that checks the result:

```ml
let computeSomethingAndFailIfWrong (x : int) =
  async {
    let! result = computeSomething x

    if result > 10 then
      failwith $"Something went wrong for input %i{x}"

    return result
  }
```

And give this to `Async.Parallel`:

```ml
async {
  let! results =
    [
      for x in [ 1; 7; 2; 3; 4; 5 ] do
        computeSomethingAndFailIfWrong x
    ]
    |> Async.Parallel

  printfn "%A" results
}
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Running this, we observe that in-progess tasks get cancelled:

```
Computation for 5 was cancelled
Computation for 7 was cancelled
System.Exception: Something went wrong for input 4
```